# How to test React Native components more than one level deep?

Tags: react-native, enzyme

The preferred method to test React Native components right now seems to be to use a combination of mocha, react-native-mock, and enzyme to shallow render components.

The problem is that shallow rendering only goes one level deep, and sometimes components have nested views that require you to test an additional level or two.

In theory, enzyme supports `mount()` to fully render a component, but in practice this fails because [react-native-mock's `View` mock does not recurse into children](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-mock/issues/76).

In light of these restrictions, how are people testing their components deeper than one render level?

Comment: question is if it is not good practise to test components in isolation anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by switching my component tests from mocha to jest and following the instructions here for snapshot testing: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html

I then added jest to my existing test target in package.json:

`"test": mocha … && jest"`

One thing to be aware of is that I did have to follow the instructions to add mocks for things I would have expected to have been mocked out of the box (eg. `TextInput`), as well as using `moduleNameMapper` to map some native components that weren't resolving properly.

Answer (score 2):

We solved the problem of getting `mount()` to work with enzyme to fully render React Native components. We wrote about it at https://blog.joinroot.com/mounting-react-native-components-with-enzyme-and-jsdom/

If you use our fork, `react-native-mock-render`, and set up jsdom, you'll be able to mount components.